# What are good references on understanding online learning?

Tags: reference-request, machine-learning, lg.learning, ai.artificial-intel, online-learning

Specifically, I'm asking for resources to learn about machine learning systems that can update their respective belief networks (or equivalent) during operation. I've even run across a few, though I failed to bookmark them.

As you might imagine, it's a rather challenging topic to search for on the internet.

Comment: When asking users to contribute to a list of answers, the question should be marked [community wiki](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11740/what-are-community-wiki-posts). I have converted this question.

Answer (score 11):

Most online learning algorithms come from at least one out of these lineages:

- the perceptron

  State of the art perceptrons are the [passive-aggressive algorithm](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.61.5120&rep=rep1&type=pdf), the [structured perceptron](http://ir.hit.edu.cn/~car/research/dishmm.pdf), and their many varieties.
- The winnow

  The winnow has been reformulated as [exponentiated gradient methods](http://www.ingentaconnect.com/content/ap/ic/1997/00000132/00000001/art02612), and can be applied to [structured problems](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.70.6635&rep=rep1&type=pdf) as well. There are also varieties that deal directly with L1 regularization (to guarantee sparsity), such as [SMIDAS](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.149.5344&rep=rep1&type=pdf).
- Stochastic gradient descent

  Stochastic gradient descent is when you apply online optimization to a possibly batch problem. State of the art algorithms are Leon Bottou's [LaSVM](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.60.9676&rep=rep1&type=pdf), [Pegasos](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.161.9629&rep=rep1&type=pdf), and many neural network algorithms can be easily trained in this setting. See the [theano tutorial](http://deeplearning.net/tutorial/) for many examples. Maybe [online EM](http://www.cs.berkeley.edu/~pliang/papers/online-naacl2009-talk.pdf) fits here.
- particle filtering

  This is also known as rao-blackwellized inference, and it allows you to update a graphical/probabilistic model as more data arrives. Some good examples are [online topic models](http://cocosci.berkeley.edu/tom/papers/topicpf.pdf) and the [NIPS tutorial on SMC](http://videolectures.net/mlss07_doucet_smcm/).

There are also some broader issues with online learning, like [online-to-batch conversion](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.68.9600&rep=rep1&type=pdf), budget techniques for online learning with kernels (like [this paper](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.72.5040&rep=rep1&type=pdf), [this paper](http://astro.temple.edu/~tua63862/ICML10_BPegasos.pdf), and [this paper](http://jmlr.csail.mit.edu/proceedings/papers/v9/wang10b/wang10b.pdf)), many different flavors of generalization bounds, [sparsity concerns](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.148.6556&rep=rep1&type=pdf) (and also the SMIDAS paper I cited above), [hashing](http://eprints.pascal-network.org/archive/00005685/01/ShiPetDroLanetal09b.pdf) to save memory, and many other issues.

Comment: Very informative answer!

Answer (score 7):

Avrim Blum as a terrific survey paper that I would recommend starting with: "Online Algorithms in Machine Learning" http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~avrim/Papers/survey.ps

Answer (score 4):

If you're looking for information on the theory behind online learning, the book by [Cesa-Bianchi and Lugosi](http://homes.dsi.unimi.it/~cesabian/predbook/) is a solid reference.

Comment: I'll look into it, thanks. That was actually one of the two suggestions Wikipedia provided (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Online_machine_learning could use some help)

Comment: Another useful source is John Langford's series of posts: http://hunch.net/?cat=7

Answer (score 4):

There is a [nice tutorial](http://ttic.uchicago.edu/~shai/icml08tutorial/) from ICML 2008 by Yoram Singer and Shai Shalev Shwartz on the theory and practice of online learning.

Answer (score 1):

Machine Learning - Course Materials - Stanford
http://www.stanford.edu/class/cs229/materials.html

Machine Learning and Artificial Intelligence Video Lectures
http://freescienceonline.blogspot.com/2007/07/machine-learning-and-artificial.html

Gaussian Processes for Machine Learning
http://www.gaussianprocess.org/gpml/

Comment: This does not talk specifically about online learning. The gaussian process book hardly mentions the online approximations to gaussian processes.